# Selecting first image in div and replacing image src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to select the first image found within a div and replace the image source. It specifically must be this method as the image doesn't have an ID (complicated to explain).

```
$('.promo-unit-site-logo-3').find('img:first').attr'('src', 'blank')')';
```

I have tried using the above code from googling around and clipping something together however I am by way of javascript a novice.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,
John

Comment: What's with the quotes outside the `attr` function, is that just a typo ?

Comment: `$('.promo-unit-site-logo-3').find('img:first').attr('src', 'blank');`

Answer (score 0):

see its working. you mistake in code.

```js
var image = $('.promo-unit-site-logo-3').find('img:first').attr('src', 'blank');
console.log(image.attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="promo-unit-site-logo-3">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/280x210" title="first image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/30x20" title="Second image">
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, the code works great. The only problem I have now is it's doing this upon DOM reaady. Is there anyway that I can pre the image loading, replace it?

Basically we have a very restrictive eCommerce platform with no access to the CMS configuration.

Using your code I can replace an image we need to on our site. Because it's dom ready, it of course shows the image then replaces it.